# Looking to install elementary os on WSL-2

Tags: release-hera, software-installation, dual-boot

So I have WSL-2 configured fully. Is there any way I can run elementary OS the same way Ubuntu runs on WSL? I don't want to use a VM nor the dual boot option so this looks like the only viable alternative.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: https://x410.dev/cookbook/wsl/installing-pantheon-desktop-on-ubuntu-wsl/

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following Gist on GitHub that may be of help:

[Instructions on how to install a custom distro in WSL2 (Windows SubSystem for Linux 2)](https://gist.github.com/artman41/858450e2c29b239d8692213b684ada25#wsl-install-another-distro)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sileshn/ElementaryWSL

Am going to try that for Elementary 6.1 on Win11 WSL2

Although installing pantheon on WSL2 Ubuntu seems the easier compared to this or creating elementary as a custom WSL2 distro

EDIT / UPDATE:

That works flawlessly. The last updated github stuff of Sailesh i mean.

Unzip and run elementary.exe OR do wsl --import thing. It's got Elementary 6. You have to apt install any stuff you need.

Will try installing gui/desktop similar to how its working for ubuntu.

Though TBH i guess MS has made both WSL & WSA in a way that we will start using any required Android/Linux apps just on the normal windows 11 desktop and slowly forget any Linux desktop or Android Launcher/Desktop/Home-Screen !

Though i have both with gui desktops, the desktop/launcher is actually only needed when you want to configure any stuff or just generally to check / explore stuff.

The very few apps i need from android & linux are better run just directly.